# Comparison of ReactJS with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular

What are the performance based advantages of ReactJS when compared to the Angular2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out this comparison of the two through which ReactJS is rendered out as the easiest to use over AngularJS. But I'd like to also stress that this is purely opinionated and this might change depending on the application being developed and its context.

[image: Comparison]

For further information, you can refer [this](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angular-vs-react-the-tie-breaker).

Comment: A comparison, if such one even can be truly made between the two, should be between the latest RC Angular 2 and React.js, not AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, I mean today:

- ReactJS is mature (version 15.x)
- whereas Angular2 is in RC5 (not mature)

So:

- `React` is a `today` or `middle term` best bet in term of performance (rendering, bundle size etc...)
- `Angular2` (*if it does what it is promised to do later!*) should be a `long term bet`.